# How to fix the top row and first column in a webpage, with only CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm building a webpage similar to the one in the figure below. The table in the webpage is built with floating divs and the number of columns and rows is variable.

Now, the question: I want to be able to scroll the webpage while maintaining the top row (X, Y, Z, W, ...) and the first column (A, B, C, D, E, F, ...) always visible. How can I do this? Is it possible with only with CSS (preferably)? Or will I have to use Javascript?

[image: Mockup of webpage]

Comment: No, it's not that simple. When I use "position:fixed" on the first column, the first column no longer scrolls vertically. I want it to scroll vertically but not horizontally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible with CSS only.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. Use "position:fixed" on the elements you want to have visible always.

Comment: No, it's not that simple. When I use "position:fixed" on the first column, the first column no longer scrolls vertically. I want it to scroll vertically but not horizontally.

Comment: Ah, that is to mention.. 
I think there is no way you can do this with CSS. I recommend the javascript framework JQuery if you're finished trying with CSS.

Comment: Yes, it seems it is not possible (with CSS only).

Answer (score 0):

Use an iFrame? 
Or have a div with all the contents in and add `overflow:scroll`. the top and side div's can then remain stationary.

Answer (score 0):

Check out datatables.net the jquery plugin has a fixed header and fixed column feature

Fixed column - has a few options see example links at bottom of the page
http://datatables.net/release-datatables/extras/FixedColumns/index.html

Fixed header
http://datatables.net/extras/fixedheader/